# Drupal9 custom module

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-9

Can anyone plz provide me the zip file of a simple custom module in drupal 9. I  am having so much trouble in making a simple module. I have seen so many tutorials but thats not working. Please give a zip file of a custom module. It's always showing page not found.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: take a look at this documentation: https://www.drush.org/11.x/commands/generate/
you can user drush to generate a custom module

Answer (score 0):

Look for Module `capitalcamp_glue` in Google. In GIT it is an easy example i use too.